# vuforia video playback 4.2.3 , video disappears when the reference image is removed

Tags: ios, xcode6, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using vuforia videoplayback 4.2.3 for playing a video in texture. It works fine as long as the reference image is kept. But if the reference image is removed the video disappears. My requirement is to continue playing the video even if the reference image is removed. I enabled "extended tracking" but nothing happened. In many youtube videos I saw 3D images working after the reference image is removed but not for videos. Pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use an auxiliar boolean variable, that changes calue when video is playing and the tracking is OK. So when tracking is lost, instead of stop rendering, you put the plane that has the videotexture in a fixed place and scale, looking to the camera. Then when tracking is positive you get the video asset (plane) tracked to the marker.
Hope you got the idea, and still need this advice.